# To add the result set values from the servlet to the check box in jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets, resultset

I need help in adding the result set values from servlet to the checkbox in jsp without using JSTL implementation

**Work flow :**

1.The user enters a value in text box and clicks search button

2.On clicking search the servlet is called. The servlet focuses on the database implementation and forward the result set values to the same jsp page from where the request comes.

3.The result set values should be displayed in the form of a check box in jsp

**Issue:**

The result set values are getting printed in my jsp page. Instead of printing all the values,I need to display my result set values as check box values in my jsp page. My result set size is 3.

This is my code:

**Productlist.jsp**

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@page import="web.Products"%>
<%@page import="java.util.ArrayList"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
       <title>Products</title>
</head>

<body>
 <form method="post" align="center" action="ProductList">

Company Name:<input type="text" size="20" id="company" name="company" />
<input type="submit" value="search"/>
  <%
  List<Products> pdts = (List<Products>) request.getAttribute("list");
  if(pdts!=null){
    for(Products prod: pdts){
       out.println("<br/>" + prod.getProductname());
     }
  }
%>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**ProductList.java(servlet-code)**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;


public class ProductList extends HttpServlet {

    static final String dbURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pdt";
    static final String dbUser = "root";
    static final String dbPass = "root";

    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8"); 
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        Connection connection = null;   
        List<Products> pdt = new ArrayList<Products>();

        try{
            String company =request.getParameter("company");
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection (dbURL,dbUser,dbPass);
            String sql="select product_pck from comp_pdt_list where company_name='"+company+"'";
            PreparedStatement prep = connection.prepareStatement(sql); 
            rs=prep.executeQuery();
if(rs!=null)
 {
while(rs.next()) 
  { 
    Products prod=new Products();
      prod.setProductname(rs.getString("product_pck"));
      pdt.add(prod);
}
       request.setAttribute("list",pdt);

            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Productlist.jsp");    
                    rd.forward(request,response); 
                    return;
 }
prep.close();

       }
     catch(Exception E){
//Any Exceptions will be caught here
System.out.println("The error is"+E.getMessage());

    }  

        finally {
            try {
                connection.close();
            } 
        catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("The error is"+ex.getMessage());
            }
                }

}

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(Products prod: pdts){
       out.println("<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"prod\" value=\"" + prod.getProductname() + "\">" + prod.getProductname() + "<br>");
     }
```